# SQL Server : CASE date 30 days before enddate

Tags: sql-server, date, case

I'm looking to be able to set a specific code depending on date.

One is "active" when today's date is between startdate and enddate. The other one shall apply 30 days prior to the enddate.

I've tried something like this however, can't get the 30 day prior cast to work.
Any help appreciated.

Example:

```
DECLARE @now datetime = GETDATE()

UPDATE table
SET CODE = CASE 
              WHEN @now BETWEEN i.StartDATE AND i.EndDATE 
                 THEN 'Active'
              WHEN i.EndDATE <= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) 
                 THEN 'Expiring' 
              ELSE 'Cancelled'
           END
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I think you've got your condition wrong.  If you want to mark the code as expiring if today is within 30 days of the enddate, then you need to calc `getdate() >= dateadd(day, -30, i.enddate)`

Comment: @Beth - isn't that just the same as what is in the OP as you reversed the comparison operator from less than to greater than?

Comment: It would help if you posted where it goes wrong? Post the sample data you provide (`startDate`, `endDate`, `Now`) and what you then expect to get as an assignment value for `CODE` and what you are getting right now for `CODE`.

Comment: @Igor he wants to compare 30 days prior to the enddate with today,  The enddate could be tomorrow, and it could be expiring.  Subtracting 30 days from today won't identify that condition.  Actually, the best thing to do would be to include those calculations in a `select` clause so it's clear what's going on.

Comment: how do you want to handle the condition where they're expiring but also active?

Comment: Well, it shall not say active then only expiring. Only one code shall be inserted.

Comment: so if they're both active and expiring, you want the expiring condition to win?  Then you need to test for your expiring condition first, then active, then cancelled.

Comment: Thank you Beth, I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the 30 days first as this also encompases the status active but superseeds it. Also to make the logic a little easier to read I used `DATEDIFF`.

```
DECLARE @now datetime = GETDATE()

UPDATE table
SET CODE = CASE 
  -- its between the start/end dates AND falls within 30 days of the end date
  WHEN @now BETWEEN i.StartDATE AND i.EndDATE AND DATEDIFF(day, @now, i.EndDATE) < 30
     THEN 'Expiring'
  -- else it falls between the start/end date
  WHEN @now BETWEEN i.StartDATE AND i.EndDATE 
     THEN 'Active'
  -- it falls outside the start/end dates
  ELSE 'Cancelled'
END
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I'll try this and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I don't think you need the first condition for 'expiring,'  if there's less than (or equal to?) 30 days between the end date and now, you know it's expired.  Also don't think you need to test the startDate to determine if it's active, as long as it's not expired, @now is either before the end date (active) or after it (cancelled.)  the value of the start date doesn't matter.

Comment: @Beth - You do because a negative result could occur with the right conditions if you do not include it. Example would be a timespan that occurred in the past. IMO start date is probably critical as it might not have occurred yet in which case the period is not active, I assume that the state would then lead to `cancelled` but maybe that's a bad assumption as the OP never specified what should happen in that scenario.

Comment: Exactly, he didn't specify how he wanted conditions ending in the past (obsolete?  archived?) categorized.  Actually, if both the start and end dates are in the past, you can't distinguish between a cancelled status or an archived status, unless he only updates rows where the `code` value is null.

Comment: Tried the script, however the "Expiring" keeps overriding the Active code even though I set the date to 2017-xx-xx where it clearly shouldnt be expiring.

Comment: So, the (day, i.EndDATE, @now) should be the other way around. (day, @now, i.EndDATE)

Answer (score 1):

If you're having problems getting the conditions set the way you want, try simplifying them and checking the values in a SELECT statement.  Then it should be clear how you need to set your comparisons.

```
DECLARE @now datetime = GETDATE()

UPDATE table
  SET CODE = CASE 
                when @now < i.startdate then 'future'  -- or null
                WHEN @now > i.EndDATE then 'Cancelled'
                when @now >= DATEADD(day, -30, i.EndDATE) THEN 'Expiring' 
                else 'Active'
             END
where code is null or code <> 'Cancelled'
```

this assumes that when a row is both active and expiring, you want the expiring code to win.  Even if the start date is the day before the end date, it's both active and expiring and you want expiring set.

Comment: I like your answer better, deleted mine

Comment: I mess this stuff up all the time, have strategies for figuring out how to do these types of comparisons.

Comment: What this does not take into consideration though is if the start date has not yet occurred. That would produce  a result of `Active` which is probably not correct. With the alternate solution it would result in `Cancelled` (*which also might be wrong but might be closer to a valid status than active*).

Comment: yes, @Igor, I agree, he hasn't specified the behavior he wants when the start date is in the future, only that it's not expiring or cancelled.  He may have posted a simplified example with additional conditions.  I can add that condition to this answer, though.

Comment: Thank for taking "future" in to consideration. I've added this since didn't think of this... However, for some reason "Expiring" overrides even when it should be only active.

Comment: @user3052850, only reason I can think of why you'd have active instead of expiring is if you wanted 30 days before the end to be active.  Can you give an example of the start date, end date, and now where it says expiring but you want active?  It helps us if you give examples of your input and expected output.  You probably also don't want to change every row every time, only if needed.